# jQuery Ajax send twice the second submit and three times the third submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file "popup_or_abbort.php" If the user have a request already, then the request will be abborted and the row in the db will be deleted with mysql_query. If I go on the page for the first time and send a request, it sends the request once. If I submit a second time it abborts the request. If I send a request again, without updating the page, it sends the request twice. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#request").click(function(){

      uid = "<?php echo $user_id; ?>";        
      pid = "<?php echo $p_id; ?>";           

      $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/scripts/popup_or_abbort.php",
        data: {"uid" : uid, "pid" : pid},
        success: function(data){
          if (data == "send_ok") {            

            $('#popup').fadeIn(300);
            $('#sendbutton').click(function(){
              pn = "<?php echo $p_name; ?>";
              un = "<?php echo $username; ?>";
              oid = "<?php echo $p_owner_id; ?>";
              app = $('#application').val();

              $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/scripts/send_team_request.php",
                data: {"uid" : uid, "pid" : pid, "pn" : pn, "un" : un, "oid" : oid, "app" : app},
                success: function(data){
                  $('#request').html(data);
                  $('#application').val("");
                  $('#popup').fadeOut(300);

                  return false;                      
                }
              });                 
            });
          }
          else {
            $('#request').html(data);
            return false;
          }  
        }          
      }); 
  return false;              
  }); 
return false;           
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning `$('#sendbutton').click(function(){` handler inside ajax callback. It actually get's assigned new (identical) handler each time ajax callback is executed. So, upon `#sendbutton` click - multiple identical ajax requests are being executed.

Instead, delegate it once outside of ajax call:

```
$(document).on("click", "#sendbutton", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: I set $(document).on("click", "#sendbutton", function() block below the $(document).ready(function() block and now it's all fine. Thank you very much for the help, you're great!